# Ruby on Rails Handling UTF-8 within escape_javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, character-encoding

I've got a partial _searchresults.html.erb which has to be saved in UTF-8.

Then I've got some javaxript/AJAX code to render that partial:

```
<% # encoding: utf-8
%>
stopLoading();
$('#searchresults').html('<%= escape_javascript( render("shared/searchresults") ) %>');
```

Everytime I try to access the related page I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):
1: <% # encoding: utf-8
2: %>
3: stopLoading();
4: $('#searchresults').html('<%= escape_javascript( render("shared/searchresults") ) %>');
app/views/searches/index.de.js.erb:4:in  `_app_views_searches_index_de_js_erb__423966875_35661432__279394272'
```

All of my files are encoded with UTF-8 and all relevant *.erb files have the `# encoding: utf-8` magic comment.

Is there anything I can do about this?

**EDIT:**

I'm now trying to escape the js manually:

```
def my_js_escape( js )

  if( js )
    ret = js.force_encoding( 'utf-8' )

    ret.gsub!( /\\/u, '\\\\' )


    #ret.gsub!( /<\//u, '<\/' ).force_encoding( 'utf-8' )
    #ret.gsub!( /"/u, '\\"' ).force_encoding( 'utf-8' )
    #ret.gsub!( /'/u, "\\'" ).force_encoding( 'utf-8' )
    #/(\\|<\/|\r\n|[\n\r"'])/
    return ret
  else
    ''
  end
end
```

Ruby gives me the same error on every gsub call, even if I put .force_encoding on all the replacement strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it, not the prettiest solution, but I had to manually convert every string I wanted to display with:

```
def self.encode( string )
    unless string.nil?
        string.encoding == 'UTF-8'? string : string.force_encoding( 'utf-8');
    end
end
```

thx, 2potatocakes your link helped

Answer (score 1):

All these encoding issues since Ruby192 have been a pain in the butt.. Try doing this and see if it works:

```
4: $('#searchresults').html('<%= escape_javascript( render("shared/searchresults").force_encoding("utf-8") ) %>');
```

OK. So that was a fail train.. Check out this page.. It helped me fix a similar problem to the one you're looking at..

http://peppyheppy.com/2011/1/20/ruby-1-9-2-encoding-utf-8-and-rails-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii

Comment: Apologies DeX3, Try the above link instead. Let me know if it works

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to force the encoding for the output of **render**: `(render("shared/searchresults")).force_encoding("utf-8")`